# JTables : jquery.jtable.min.js?8:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jtable

I was not that really familiar with Jtables.

```
var twg = $('#twg').jtable({
    title: 'TWG Assignment',paging: true, pageSize: 10, sorting: true, defaultSorting: 'classificationcode',selecting:true,
    toolbar: {
        items: [{ 
            icon: Drupal.settings.pricelisting.url + 'sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/libraries/jTable/scripts/themes/metro/add.png',
            text: 'Add new record',
            click: function () {
                dialog.html('<h3>loading...</h3>');
                dialog.dialog('open');
                $.post(url,{req:'load-twg-and-class'}, function(response){
                    dialog.dialog(
                        'option',
                        'buttons',
                        [
                            { 
                                text:'Cancel',
                                click:function(){
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                }
                            },
                            { 
                                text: 'Save',
                                click: function(){
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url:url,
                                        data: $(this).find('form').serialize()+'&req=save-twgs', 
                                        type:'post', 
                                        success:function(r){
                                            console.debug(r);
                                            if( parseInt(r.status) == 1){
                                                $(dialog).dialog('close');
                                                twg.jtable('load');
                                            }else dialog.find('#message').html(r.message);
                                        },
                                        error: function(xhr){ 
                                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    );
                    dialog.dialog('option','title','Assign new classification to TWG');
                    dialog.dialog('option','width',600);
                    dialog.html(response);
                });
            }
        }]
    },
    actions: {
        listAction: url +'&req=twgs'
    },
    fields:{
        code : {key:true, list:false},
        name: { title:'TWG', sorting:false },
        classification: {title:'Item Classification', inputClass:'validate[required]', sorting:false, 
            display : function(data){ 
                var str = data.record ? data.record.classification.split('*') : '', html = '<ul>';
                for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
                    html += '<li style=\"list-style:circle;\">'+str[i]+'</li>';
                }
                html +='</ul';
                return html;
            } 
        }
    },
    selectionChanged:function(data){
        var selectedRows = $( twg ).jtable('selectedRows');
        if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
            selectedRows.each(function () {
            var record = $(this).data('record');
            dialog.html('<h3>loading...</h3>');
            dialog.dialog('open').dialog('option','title','Update TWG\'s assigned Classification');
            $.post(url,{req: 'load-twg-assigned-class', id : record.idnumber }, function(r){
                dialog.dialog('option','buttons',[{ text :'Cancel', click :function(){ $(this).dialog('close'); }}, { text: 'Remove Selected', click : function(){ $.ajax({ url:url, data: $(this).find('form').serialize()+'&req=remove-twgs', type:'post', success:function(r){ if( parseInt(r.status) == 1){ $(dialog).dialog('close'); twg.jtable('load'); } else dialog.find('#message').html(r.message); }, error: function(xhr){ alert(xhr.responseText); } }); } }]);
                dialog.dialog('option','width',400);
                dialog.html(r);
                twg.find('tr').removeClass('jtable-row-selected');
            });
         });
        }
    }
});
```

Why does it throws error after the line below:

```
twg.jtable('load');
```

Below is the error below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at b.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createRowFromRecord (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/libraries/jTable/scripts/jquery.jtable.min.js?8:36:265)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/libraries/jTable/scripts/jquery.jtable.min.js?8:37:195)
at Function.each (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/js/jquery.min.js?8:2:11937)
at b.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._addRecordsToTable (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/libraries/jTable/scripts/jquery.jtable.min.js?8:37:162)
at Object.success (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/libraries/jTable/scripts/jquery.jtable.min.js?8:35:427)
at Object.a.success (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/libraries/jTable/scripts/jquery.jtable.min.js?8:51:192)
at n (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/js/jquery.min.js?8:2:14784)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/js/jquery.min.js?8:2:15553)
at w (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/js/jquery.min.js?8:4:11395)
at XMLHttpRequest.d (http://localhost/drupal-6.28-dummy/sites/all/modules/cgb_helper_functions/js/jquery.min.js?8:4:17218)
```

Please help me with this. I really dont have any idea. Is this related to jquery issues or what? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide complete code or give url where you are getting this problem, so that it is easy to solve

Comment: the error tells you what is wrong... you have a "type" error with `data`. what line of code is throwing this?

Comment: The ```selectionChanged``` function is called with two arguments ```(event, data)``` not a single argument. Hence it was trying to process the event object as your data object